# .htaccess url: rewrite is not working on local host

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new on .htaccess My current url is :

```
 http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/details.php?p_id=999
```

and if i want to display my url like this its **work good for me.**

```
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/details/999
```

**my .htaccess code is**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www.zeeshan.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^details/([^/]+)$ details.php?p_id=$1  [NC,L]
```

My problem is that when **use this link** i can not obtain my correct answer:

```
 http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/details.php?p_id=999&p_title=nokia%20mobile%20for%20sale
```

i used this .htaccees code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www.zeeshan.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^details/(\d+)-([\w-]+)$ details.php?p_id=$1&p_title=$2 [NC,L]
```

after using this link i **want like this**:

```
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/details/999/nokia-mobile-for-sale
```

i read many time **this topic** in the given link to solve my problem but failed to get my correct out put. every time and got **page not found error**.
 [Rewriting URL with .htaccess local in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243975/rewriting-url-with-htaccess-local-in-xampp)

please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect actually. Use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www.zeeshan.com/

## convert spaces to hyphens
# executes **repeatedly** as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" $1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^details/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ details.php?p_id=$1&p_title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: this gave answer like this http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/details/189/nokia%20mobile%20for%20sale

but i want my answer like this
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/details/189/nokia-mobile-for-sale

Comment: sir any possibility that, if i have 2 pages like index.php and detail.php. if user open detail.php page in wrong way like deatilss.php my .htaccess :url redirect and open my own design 404.php page? using above .htaccess code

Comment: yes 404.php page in this i design page not found error.

Comment: I am not getting you. 404 is expected outcome and that is happening. I will be offline for 2 hours. You can open a new question to get help from SO community.

Comment: I am on mobile at present. Can you create a new question for this new problem and I will attend it once I am back online.