# Setup of rewrite mode in mac OS X 10.7.5 using XAMPP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

I need to enable the url rewriting mode to have SEO friendly url for website on PHP platform. I have installed the XAMPP server 7.0.2 in my Mac OS x 10.7.5 laptop. i have created new folder 'maxie' under the '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/' folder. 'maxie' folder contains all the file for website.

My question is how to enable the url rewriting mod and where to write the code to convert url 'http://example.com/index.html' to 'http://example.com' or http://example.com/user.php to 'http://example.com/user'. finally how to test if thats working fine.

Thanks in advance for your help. Any input is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewriting URL with .htaccess local in XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243975/rewriting-url-with-htaccess-local-in-xampp)

Comment: Thanks for you reply.I can refer for rewriting and but main question is to how to enable it.