# .htaccess URL Rewriting / Delete folders / Delete ".php"

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I work on a local projet on WAMP.

So here is my folders hierarchy :

```
- Project :
   - index.php
   - .htaccess
   - pages : 
         - animaux :
               - mammiferes.php
               - oiseaux.php
               - reptiles.php
         - infos :
               - access.php
               - contact.php
               - plan.php
         - spectacle : 
               - reserverPlace.php
               - spectacle.php
```

What I try to do is putting the goods URL cond and rules to have for example this URL : `http://localhost/ProjetSyntheseFAC/mammiferes` instead of `http://localhost/ProjetSyntheseFAC/pages/animaux/mammiferes.php` . So I have to delete folders from the URL and delete the ".php" at the end.

All i found and try either does not work or put me in Internal Servor Error.

Here is what i tried last :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mammiferes$ /pages/animaux/mammiferes.php
```

////

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)
RewriteRule !\.[a-z0-4]{2,4}$ /pages/animaux/%1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/animaux/$1 [L]
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: [Possible answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243975/rewriting-url-with-htaccess-local-in-xampp) Try using the first three lines of code and add your own `RewriteRule` which you've already done above. Try if that works, if not then check for an `error_log` as that's what Internal Server error means.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper It don't do anything the URL still the same and no error like if the htaccess don't exist

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^mammiferes$ /pages/animaux/mammiferes.php
> ```

If your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/project/` subdirectory, and the parent directory is the document root, then you'll need to remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example:

```
 RewriteRule ^mammiferes$ pages/animaux/mammiferes.php [L]
```

With the slash prefix, the *substitution* is relative to the document root. Without the slash prefix then it's relative to wherever the `.htaccess` file is located. This assumes you don't have a `RewriteBase` directive that overrides this (or set `RewriteBase` to the `/Project/` subdirectory).

The `L` flag should be included if you later add more directives.